# How to find a chunk and replace in a long string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string and I want to replace `server:${address.ip()}:3000` with `server:localhost:3000`

Here is a string

```
function(t,e,n){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0}),e.environment={production:!0,server:"localhost:3000",apikey:"XXXX"}},BRrH:function(t,e,n){t.exports=c;var r=n("bkOT")("simple-peer"),o=n("3oOE"),i=n("P7XM")
```

**What I am doing is**

update-ip.js

```
import replace from "replace-in-file";
import * as address from "address";

export class UpdateIpService {

    constructor() {

    }

    static update(filepath: string) {
        replace({
            files: filepath,
            from: /server:\s*[`'"]http?:\/\/.*?[`'"],/g,
            to: `server: 'http://${address.ip()}:3000/',`
        }).then(changes => {
            console.log(`Ip address updated in file: ${changes}`)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('File could not be found to modify')
        })
    }

}

UpdateIpService.update('./main.js')
```

How to modify, please guide!!!

Comment: What's your current code producing? (note that it would probably be better to capture the delimiter ``[`'"]`` and backreference it later)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Nothing changed

Comment: From the looks of it, you're looking to change a production bundle using string manipulation, but it's probably configurable using some config settings. I would suggest you consider understanding your config.

Comment: I agree with @MaazSyedAdeeb, I also wonder if this would have trouble with IP6.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb You're right but my case is somehow different. Node and Angular app needs to run on local machine and other angular (hosted by local machine) is running on different machine and that needs to communicate through Node app so it must know the server on which it is running. So I need to change server ip manually before hosting app on other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches http where the p is optional because of the question mark. Also if you use the trailing `,` in and you replace the full match then that comma will also be replaced.

Without matching the http part, you could match `server:` and then match from the starting delimiter until the closing delimiter.

As mentioned in the comments, you could use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to the first capturing group so that for example `server:"localhost:3000'` does not match.

```
\bserver:\s*([`'"]).*?\1
```

**Explanation**

- `\bserver\s*` Match server followed by 0+ whitespace characters and use a word boundary `\b` to make sure server is not part of a longer word
- `` ([`'"]) `` Capture one of the matched characters from the character class in the first capturing group
- `.*?` Match 0+ times any character non greedy
- `\1` Match backreference to captured group 1

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EX0BOO/1)

For example:

```
from: /\bserver:\s*([`'"]).*?\1/g,
```

Comment: can you give me a final regex because I am too weak in regex. Thanks

Comment: @WasiF I have added an example of the code at the bottom of my answer.